# Find an explicit isomorphism from a curve of genre zero to the Riemann sphere

Tags: riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves

I can't figure out this exercise:
i have this singular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2\mathbb{C}$ given by
$\{[X,Y,Z]\in \mathbb{P}^2\mathbb{C}:X^2Y^2+Y^2Z^2+X^2Z^2=0\}$, I have shown that its desingularization is a curve of genus zero, but now I must find an explicit isomorphism with the Riemann sphere.
I don't know how to do it, could anybody help me with that? thank you

Comment: The word in English is "genus", not "genre". The plural is "genera".

Comment: This sounds like homework, so here are some hints. (1) There is an easy isomomorphism between this curve and $U^2+V^2+W^2=0$ (also in $\mathbb{P}^2$), do you see it? (2) $U^2+V^2+W^2$ is a conic and can be approached as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Rational_curves

Comment: no, i can't see the isomorphism between the curve and $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2=0$ because i thought $ X \mapsto XY, Y \mapsto YZ, Z \mapsto XZ$ but it doesen't seem to be working...